# Using Reflection to auto-fill in defaults in an object where possible

Tags: java, reflection, guava

Here is some code I've been twiddling with to try and lazily fill in fields in object, mostly for object factories in JUnit but it could be quite a useful method to have.

```
    private void lazyObjectFill(Object profil) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    final Method[] list = profil.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : list) {
        if (Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()) && m.getName().startsWith("set")) {

            final Class< ?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
                final Class< ?> clazz = parameterTypes[0];
                if (clazz == String.class) {
                    log.info("Invoking " + m.getName() + " with [\"\"]");
                    m.invoke("");
                } else if (clazz.isPrimitive() && Defaults.defaultValue(clazz) != null) {
                    log.info("Invoking " + m.getName() + " with [" + Defaults.defaultValue(clazz) + "]");
                    m.invoke(Defaults.defaultValue(clazz));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

We get the following exception when running this code on an object.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
```

The exception occurs when running m.invoke(""); on a string setter.

---

Updated source code for the benefit of the googlers.

```
private void lazyObjectFill(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    final Method[] list = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : list) {
        method.setAccessible(true);
        if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers()) && method.getName().startsWith("set")) {

            final Class< ?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
                final Class< ?> clazz = parameterTypes[0];
                if (clazz == String.class) {
                    log.info("Invoking " + method.getName() + " with [\"\"]");
                    method.invoke(obj, "");
                } else if (clazz.isPrimitive() && Defaults.defaultValue(clazz) != null) {
                    log.info("Invoking " + method.getName() + " with [" + Defaults.defaultValue(clazz) + "]");
                    method.invoke(obj, Defaults.defaultValue(clazz));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `method.setAccessible(true);` This means you can change the private fields and is very dangerous to use. Also in your code you are only changing public methods, thus no need for setAccessible

Comment: One other thing. You should also test for `method.getName().startsWith("is")` as that is getters for Boolean

Comment: .startsWith("is") serves little purpose since we're trying to set values not get values, but you're correct it is the usual way of writing getters for boolean fields.

If I recall correctly, combining method.setAccessible(true) and then checking for public lets us assign to package-protected/default values.  Mind you it should probably have a caveat about that, you're correct that writing to private fields is dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, but methods are static and they need an object on which to invoke them.

i.e.

```
m.invoke(profil, "");
```

and

```
m.invoke(profil, Defaults.defaultValue(clazz));
```

You were (unknowingly) trying to execute the method on a string object without parameters. And since the string class does not have that method, it had to fail. Details can be found in [the Method javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)).

BTW: Static methods are invoked like this:

```
method.invoke(null, params);
```

Comment: Yup that's correct. It actually dawned on me moments after posting this in a real face-palm. Thanks for a rapid reply!

Comment: What do you mean by methods are static?

Comment: @mR_fr0g He means that `Method` objects are static in that they refer to a particular method on a class (which could itself be static or not) but they aren't tied to any _instance_ of that class. Thus, an instance has to be provided to invoke a `Method` that refers to a non-static method.

Comment: @ColinD exactly. as opposed to languages like javascript where this kind of thing works: `var myMethod = myObj.methodName; myMethod(param1, param2)` (invoked on object myObj)

Answer (score 2):

You know that [invoke](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method of Method takes two arguments ? As a consequence, I guess you wrote

```
m.invoke(profil, "")
```

Besides, I would personnally not have separated String from other objects.

And finally, to correctly identify obejct fields, i would have preferred a mixed approach

1. Use an enumeration of non static Field members
2. Use [BeanInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) to access bean properties.

Comment: This method only supports strings & primitives (or wrappers for primitives). Defaults from guava provides all the primitives and combined with strings you will be able to fill most simple objects. 

Perhaps a separate mechanic for empty collections would be nice.

Comment: Yes, BeanInfo is definitely the way to go for identifying setters (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the [`Method.invoke()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) is the object which will invoke the method.

For example in your case `m.invoke(profil, "");` or `m.invoke(profil, Defaults.defaultValue(clazz));`